# need help finding the name of a book about psychic powers, aliens, and brain in a vat type plot

Tags: aliens, novel, psychic, story-identification

The cover has a guys face wrapped in gauze on a background of fire. The book is from the point of view of a young guy who is an arsonist that discovers that he has pyrokinesis (can start fires with his mind). He meets some other people with psychic powers and discovers that reality is actually fake and that we are brains in a vat on an alien spaceship. They end up taking control of some alien bodies somehow towards the end and live their lives as aliens on some planet that they find.

I read this book about 12 years ago I do not know how old the book was when I read it. Ive searched for it for many years but cannot remember any details significant enough to put into a search engine. Please help. :)

Answer (score 2):

[Magic Fire](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671020579) by Christopher Pike

[image: cover]

> A young man who has been fascinated with fire since childhood,
>   high-school senior--and pyromaniac--Mark Charm unleashes his obsession
>   on the dry hills and valleys of Southern California.

From the School Library Journal review:

> ...aliens have harvested human brains and are keeping them in vats,
>   but the humans don't realize this has happened-but this is not what
>   has really happened at all.